# Compound type in java

Tags: java, compound-type

In open-jdk `7-b147` in class `com.sun.tools.javac.code.Type` we have the following method

```
public boolean isCompound(){
    return tsym.completer==null
    // Compound types can't have a completer.  Calling
    // flags() will complete the symbol causing the
    // compiler to load classes unnecessarily.  This led
    // to regression 6180021.
    && (tsym.flags() & COMPOUND)!=0;

}
```

What does mean compound type in Java?

Comment: Link to source: http://www.docjar.com/html/api/com/sun/tools/javac/code/Type.java.html#331

Comment: I think it's just when you have a generic type that uses `&`: `<L extends List<T> & RandomAccess>`. Not confident enough about that to put it as an answer though.

Comment: The only "right" answer here is that it's undefined. When you delve into `com.sun.*`, you're entering a land of magic and dragons, Sun could've done whatever they wanted to, it's implementation defined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Researching on Google, they appear to be an academically proposed "extension" to Java.

"Compound types" are described as a specifier for reference-types which must implement multiple classes or interfaces.  This is intended to help static verifiability & compile-time correctness when multiple APIs (interfaces) must all be implemented.

Invented example:

```
[CustomerService,IRpcGateway,IOSGiComponent] custSvc = new CustomerService();
```

I found the following links:

- http://zenger.org/jaco/cjava.html
- http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.39.4375&rep=rep1&type=pdf

Comment: I'm not 100% certain -- the links above are what I found. As @Boann says, it could also be related to generic types with multiple bounds.. Without going into further analysis, I'm not going to rule any possibilities out.

Answer (score 1):

The TypeVar class in Type.java has the following comment that I think explains the role of COMPOUND type quite well:

```
    /** The bound of this type variable; set from outside.
     *  Must be nonempty once it is set.
     *  For a bound, `bound' is the bound type itself.
     *  Multiple bounds are expressed as a single class type which has the
     *  individual bounds as superclass, respectively interfaces.
     *  The class type then has as `tsym' a compiler generated class `c',
     *  which has a flag COMPOUND and whose owner is the type variable
     *  itself. Furthermore, the erasure_field of the class
     *  points to the first class or interface bound.
     */
```

So as was already mentioned above, a COMPOUND type seems to model the type of a bound of a type variable that is composed of multiple interfaces like:

```
class Example<T extends List<T> & Serializable>
```